# From my early age vs From an early age

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-meaning

When I'm going to start a sentence with **From my early age** grammar checker shows an error. It's suggest me to use **From an early age**

Is there any major different with both of the term.

Answer (score 2):

"From an early age" sounds much more natural. The phrase should be followed immediately in the sentence by a noun or pronoun representing the person to whom the phrase applies.

Comment: **From an early age, I had a strong penchant for robotics** 

This is the best practice you want to say.

Comment: "From an early age, I had a strong penchant for robotics." This reads well.

Comment: You can say **From my earliest years** or **from (my) early childhood**, but not **from my early age**.

Comment: You could also say ***(In / during)*** *my early* ***years***, *I [something].*